# Access inherited functions from an abstract class inside a TypeScript module

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have an abstract class in TypeScript that I am inheriting for every feature module in my Angular app. This has worked as long as that class was part of the project. Here is a shortened equivalent to the class (it's called Patchbay).

```
export abstract class Patchbay<A extends AuthSocket> {
    protected readonly sockets = {};

    constructor() {
        this.sockets = {};
    }

    protected addSocket = (name: string, socket: Socket) {
        this.sockets[name] = socket;
    }

    auth = (socket?: A) A => {
          // do random stuff
    }
}
```

Now I've decided to put it into a node module of its own to be able to use it on several projects. The trouble is that now I can only access the functions (addSocket, auth) from withhin the subclass that inherits from the abstract class Patchbay, if I use 'super.auth()', but not if I use 'this.auth()'. And I cannot access them at all from outside the class.

Here is the tsconfig of the Patchbay module:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "lib": [
             "es2015",
             "dom"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
   },
   "include": ["./src"],
   "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/_tests/**"] 
}
```

And here is the resulting patchbay.d.ts (again stripped down to the essentials):

```
export declare abstract class Patchbay<A extends AuthSocket> {
    protected readonly sockets: {
        [key: string]: Socket;
    };
    protected constructor();
    protected addSocket: (name: string, socket: Socket) => void;
    auth: (socket?: A | undefined) => A;
}
```

Now, I kind of assume that I need to declare the module and the class properly for the consuming project to be able to view type Patchbay properly. But where do I do that? The patchbay.d.ts is generated automatically, so I cannot put anything in there. Unfortunately, all tutorials I could find only create extremely minimal modules as examples and so they don't cover that. Also, the TypeScript documentation itself is rather vague on the matter of *where* to declare namespaces, modules, etc.

Any help or finger pointing to the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you use `public` instead of `protected` you'll be able to access it outside the module

Comment: No, it doesn't make a difference. The method auth() is public and it is not accessible (I tried with qualifier public and without, which should default to public afaik), and I want addSocket() not to be visible to the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first boil down your problem to the essence:

```js
class A {
    auth = () => { console.log('method a') }
}

class B extends A {
    method() {
        super.auth();
    }
}

new B().method()
```

So why does it happen?

Because [class members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields) do not live on the prototype chain. Each instance of class `A` or any class derived from `A` has **it's own copy** of that function. You may have some insight looking at how they're created in [desugared code](https://tsplay.dev/N9AKJN):

```ts
var A = /** @class */ (function () {
    function A() {
        this.auth = function () { console.log('method a'); };
    }
    return A;
}());
```

That's why you can still access it by `this.auth()` but not by `super.auth()`.
The solution is simple. Rewrite it as a [class method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#methods):

```js
class A {
    auth() { console.log('method a') }
}

class B extends A {
    method() {
        super.auth();
    }
}

new B().method()
```

You may also need to check other code calling rewriten functions. As the `this` value may differ depending on how they are called now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the tip for seeing desugared code, I will use this in the future. However, this isn't quite the solution for my problem, because this and super both work when the abstract class is in the same project, but it didn't work when I imported it from a different one.

Oddly enough, I created a new, blank project to do the very same thing, and suddenly it works. I wish I knew why, but after two days of trying to figure this out, I've decide to just accept it as working and move on to keep my schedule. Maybe I'll find time for it later.

Comment: Your question has exact compile target `es5`. If you change it to a higher version (es2015 for example) the typescript error will be gone. But you'll still meet runtime consequences. While abstract class declares `auth` as a class property. Implementing class is free to implement it any way. Either as a property or as a class member. But in runtime only class member will work properly. https://tsplay.dev/wXRD8m

Comment: Ha, you are right. I totally did not see that. That was the difference. I accepted your answer. Implementing it as a class method works fine. Thanks again!